# How to get a callback from TextArea on each change?

Tags: codenameone

in my app, when editing a record, I've added an `ActionListener` to save a temporary copy of the edited values for each field automatically, so that if the app is put in the background and then stopped, the edited values can be recovered when the app is started up again.

However, with the `TextAreas` it doesn't work since actionListeners don't get called unless the user takes some action (like leaving the field). I need to use the TextArea since there can be multiple lines of text, so using a DataChangedListener for a TextField as suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441768/how-to-get-an-event-for-every-change-in-a-codenameone-textfield) does not seem a viable solution. And being able to save the TextAreas is important to achieve good UX since the user likely loses more work when text is dropped than if for example a value set in a Picker is lost.

Is there another way to achieve this result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` allows multiple lines using `setSingleLineTextArea(false)`. When invoked it will function similarly to `TextArea`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I somehow had the impression that TextField was limited to only a single line.